# PubNub: after enabling Access Manager, unable to publish messages

Tags: ruby, pubnub

I am using the ruby PubNub SDK on the server side and javascript SDK on the web front end.

After enabling the Access Manager, the javascript subscribers had no issues with subscribe calls. But the ruby code returns a 403 when "publish" is called.

I have granted access to a channel without auth_key (access to all). Any thoughts on the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out I forgot granting the write access to the channel.